# vuejs vuex firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

to com um problema para montar minha referencia do firebase seguinte

```
export default {
        firebase () {
            return {
                gastos: db.ref(`user/${this.uid}/shop/`), 
            }
        },
        computed: {
            uid () {
                return this.$store.getters.getUser.uid
            },
        }
    }
```

o que acontece é que aqui `gastos: db.ref(1user/${this.uid}/shop/')` meu `this.uid` ainda não foi definido na minha store e não monta minha referencia do firebase

mas se eu utilizar `{{uid}}` no template ta ok, o que eu to fazendo errado?

Comment: Tenta utilizar no metodo mounted, acredito que no computed algumas coisas nao estejam ainda prontas.

Comment: @narukaioh agradeço a ajuda, não funcionou cmg pq acredito estar com erro de assync do firebase com vuex

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você precise retornar um valor padrão enquanto ainda não tem o valor do banco, ou augardar o valor chegar para exibir a página:

```
export default {
    firebase () {
        return {
            gastos: db.ref(`user/${this.uid}/shop/`), 
        }
    },
    computed: {
        uid () {
            const ret = (this.$store.getters.getUser & this.$store.getters.getUser.uid) ? this.$store.getters.getUser.uid : "valor-padrao";
            return ret;
        },
    }
}
```